# How to mask password in android using java?

Tags: android, passwords, maskedtextbox

I am creating a Log-In page, Where I need to mask the password field. I dunno the syntax.I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

In the input field tag, use the type as password and your field will be created with masked input.

```
<INPUT TYPE="PASSWORD" NAME="XXXX">
```

Comment: @pranayanand: You should accept the correct answer or post it yourself - A "Thank you" is not really going to help anyone.

Comment: @pranayanand: - Please add your answer here. It will help feature.